# Setting up Drupal with an existing MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a website which is linked to a MySQL database; my DB has a table 'users' which is all nicely structured and already integrated with some desktop applications (i.e., can't be changed).

I have just set up Drupal with the Webform module and have cloned my registration form over. The Drupal version stores everything differently internally of course, and my challenge is to get my Drupal webform to save to my existing well-structured database.

There is a hook_webform_component_presave function in my webform.api.php file which I believe does the saving, should I intercept the call here and call my own database?

Comment: So you want Drupal and your own website to share a users table, right?

Comment: I think he/she's trying to use a Drupal webform to add users to his/her other site? Is that correct? If so, is that all you're looking to use the Drupal site for? If it is--and it's not just one of the functions of your new Drupal site--it seems like a bit of overkill.

Comment: @UnsettlingTrend We want Drupal for all the styling and other modules etc. We have an existing MySQL database linked to our website, we want to replace the old site with the new Drupal site and make Drupals webforms integrate with our existing MySQL DB. Yes we would like to only maintain our original users table, so if Drupal could just forward all form input to our own script that would be ideal.

Comment: If you actually want to replace your site with a Drupal site, I would think you'd be better off in the long run to just migrate whatever data you have in your current MySQL DB into Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter form's submit action like this (from your module of course):

```
function your-module-name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'your-form-id'){
        $form['#submit'][]='save_users';
    }
}

function save_users($form, &$form_state){
 // Do your user saving magic here

}
```

Actually, this way you are adding your function as extra one. Default one will also be called (since this way `save_users()` is added to `$form['submit']` array of actions.